# heatmap.2 does not show the color key

Tags: r, heatmap

My codes:

```
heatmap.2(cor_r, cellnote = sym2, notecol = "black", key = T, keysize = 0.5, key.par = list, Rowv = as.dendrogram(hclust.signs), Colv = as.dendrogram(hclust.areas), trace = "none", margins = c(10,10), col = my_palette, breaks = col_breaks, lmat=rbind(4:3,2:1))
```

Two problems:

1. No color key is shown.
2. When I rerun the codes, RStudio is broken down.

Answer (score 0):

Though don't know why, "breaks = col_breaks" is the reason. Deleting this part will get everything right.

Answer (score 0):

I know you've fixed your problem, but in case someone comes across this problem while googling -- try dev.off() before replotting, and resize the Rstudio plot window to be larger w the cursor.